# How to know where to render more information

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying data in divs that floats left on each other. I don't know how many divs that is displayed in one row due to screen size ( Can be one can be 10 ). Here is my scenario. Let's say my current screen size let me display 5 components in one row.

```
-c-c-c-c-c-
-c-c-c-c-c-
-c-c
```

Let's say every **c** is a React component. If I click first row third component I want to display more information under that row. Not next to the div. How can I find out where to paint the more information component?

Comment: I think last time I did anything like this I did something hideous involving identifying the clicked item, looping over it and subsequent elements until the top offset changed and inserting before that … and rerunning the positioning logic on resize events.

Comment: I see Google uses this when you are in the google search for images. But then I need to know about the DOM right. Or did you put a resize handler and knew how many div that could fit in the container?

Comment: Does the info need to take up the full width of the row? I assume that you also don't want the info to overlap the row underneath the selected component (but instead push the row underneath down)?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ferigomutu/1/edit?css,js,output blorb

Comment: This does not work. It should push the second round down. @limelights

Comment: The info should take up the whole row. Yes the next row should be pushed down @robertklep

Comment: You should be able to solve this with CSS. The code provided solves your issue with where to render the extra information.

Comment: The code does not solve my problem. You are painting it position absolute. Try to add 30 **C** components in your code and click the first row. Every other click me should drop below your green panel. @limelights

Comment: Yes, of course, but what I meant was this is not related to React.

Answer (score 0):

This might be considered kind of "jank" but what if you had the element you clicked on expand invisibly -- by adding like an empty div or whatever on the bottom of it that has a set height but gave it a fixed width of 100% of the container -- and placed whatever information you wanted in there?

That way, the entire row that your clicked div was on would expand to accommodate that new div you placed on the bottom of it, and you could just place any pertinent information in there?

Comment: I would still don't know where to render the invisible div. After first component, second, third, ..... I don't know how many that fits in the DOM. I think I must use resize event..... @Pytth